# IIS7 returning 400 bad request on GET request

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

i have setup farm on IIS7. When i sent long length get request it gets HTTP 400 error from IIS. The lenght of query string is from 50 to 8192 chars. The length value of paramters in query string is from 1 to 4000 chars.

How can solve this issue on IIS?

Comment: This may help you -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762387/issue-with-url-length-in-iis7-windows-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

Did Chida's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762387/issue-with-url-length-in-iis7-windows-server-2008) help you?  If so either post your own answer or provide us more details to help you with.